# USB Keyboard does not work with Grub

Tags: grub, keyboard

I am setting up Arcade Puppy http://scottjarvis.com/page105.htm on an old Dell GX50 PC.

Instead of using a PS2 style keyboard which I don't have I opted for a low profile generic USB keyboard.

The problem is that once installed to the hard disk the GRUB boot menu does not recognize  the USB Keyboard so I cannot choose the boot option to start Linux, also there isn't the normal default timeout setup.

The USB keyboard works the BIOS settings fine and worked okay when booting off the live CD to install Linux.

Has anyone got any suggestions or will I be forced to find a PS2 keyboard?

Comment: Is this grub legacy or grub 2? Googling suggests this probably a bios problem. Can you list your current setting assocated with USB? Is there any setting like "enable IRQ for USB"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem with my wireless keyboard (and running Puppy too, even if it's not related...) you have to **enable** in your BIOS `USB Device Legacy Support`.

Find it in some submenu, for example `Integrated Peripherals`.